# Gnome-terminal autogen.sh fails on vte-2.91 >= 0.45.0

Tags: gnome-terminal, vte

I wanted to change my terminal to enable e.g. mouse interaction. So I got the gnome-terminal code, but when I wanted to generate it (without changing anything), the following problem occured:

When I run `./autogen.sh --without-pcre2` I get the error message `Requested 'vte-2.91 >= 0.45.0' but version of vte is 0.42.5`.

So I've tried to install vte-2.91 higher than 0.45.0 but the highest I could find was 0.44.2 (and I could not install that either)

Does anyone know how to get a vte-2.91 version >= 0.45.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution myself.
just run`sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-terminal` .
Also to get the Code one can simply use `apt-get source gnome-teminal`

or for the VTE-Code: `apt-get source libvte-2.91-0` .